# Load iframe with link from drop down list

Tags: php, html, iframe, drop-down-menu

I have the basics working, I just need the correct src to get the link from a drop down list. Code so far:

```
<form name="dropdownMenu" method="post">
<select name="Select1" style="width: 128px">
    <option value="pages/page1.php">Page1</option>
    <option value="pages/page2.php">Page2</option>
</select>
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="GO"
onclick='document.getElementById("content").
src="THIS IS WHAT I CANT MAKE WORK";'>
```

If I change the src to "pages/page1.php" it loads the iframe fine, just can't seem to get it to load the value from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your SELECT an id and then reference the value of the SELECT

```
<form name="dropdownMenu" method="post">
<select id="Select1" name="Select1" style="width: 128px">
    <option value="pages/page1.php">Page1</option>
    <option value="pages/page2.php">Page2</option>
</select>
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="GO"
onclick='document.getElementById("content").
src=document.getElementById("Select1").value;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function newSrc() {
  var e = document.getElementById("MySelectMenu");
  var newSrc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("MyFrame").src=newSrc;
 }
</script>

<select id="MySelectMenu">
<option value="http://www.example.com">Website</option>
</select>

<button onClick="newSrc();">Load new source</button>
```